# Using azure API management restrict the api call based on the JWT token claim

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

My project using  api mangement service as azure APIM.I am trying to validate the claim using APIM Product policy .If the claim is not valid return an error otherwise allow to access the end point.Following is my policy

```
   <policies> <inbound> <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
    ------------
    ------------ 
</validate-jwt> 
<choose> 
<when condition="@(context.Request.Method != "POST" && ((Jwt)context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].Claims["role"]!= "Owner") && (string)context.Api.Path =="/api/user"> 
<return-response>
 <set-status code="403" reason="Forbidden" />
</return-response>
 </when> </choose>
<base /> 


 </inbound> <backend> <base /> </backend> <outbound> <base /> </outbound> <on-error> <base /> </policies>
```

But even if the role is not owner user can able to access the /api/user path
how to validate correctly ?

```
JWT calims are
 "userrole": "[Owner,Admin]",
 "email": "test@gmail.com"
```

Comment: If it helps you, please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example shows how to use the Validate JWT policy to authorize access to operations **based on token claims value**.

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" require-scheme="Bearer" output-token-variable-name="jwt">
    <issuer-signing-keys>
        <key>{{jwt-signing-key}}</key> <!-- signing key is stored in a named value -->
    </issuer-signing-keys>
    <audiences>
        <audience>@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host)</audience>
    </audiences>
    <issuers>
        <issuer>contoso.com</issuer>
    </issuers>
    <required-claims>
        <claim name="userrole" match="any">
            <value>Owner</value>
            <value>Admin</value>
        </claim>
    </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Request.Method == "POST" && !((Jwt)context.Variables["jwt"]).Claims["group"].Contains("Owner"))">
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="403" reason="Forbidden" />
        </return-response>
    </when>
</choose>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT).

Comment: userrole is not  a single value .in claim its string ,which contains "[Owner,Admin]".required calim accept exact match only,am i right ?

Comment: what is jwt-signing-key ?

Comment: getting an error Cannot find a property 'jwt-signing-key'

Comment: A list of Base64-encoded security keys used to validate signed tokens. If you do not have jwt-signing-key, you can remove it as it is not required.

Comment: userrole is not a single value .in claim its string ,which contains "[Owner,Admin]".required claim accept exact match only,am i right ? how to iterate each one by one

Comment: `all` - every claim value in the policy must be present in the token for validation to succeed.

- `any` - at least one claim value must be present in the token for validation to succeed.

Comment: If you want to owner and admin both in the token for validation you can set match as `all`